# SSO from custom application to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a custom web application that authenticates against Active Directory. I need to provide single sign on from my application TO SharePoint.

There are plenty of resources describing how to authenticate from sharepoint to a custom application, but I have not found any describing authentication from an external system to sharepoint **where both applications authenticate against the same domain.**

**Use case**
1. User logs into my application via form
2. User clicks link to sharepoint
3. New window opens and user is logged into sharepoint

What options do I have? I have read about Secure Store Services (SSS), but it appears that this is for authenticating a user between 2 separate user bases. Both my application and sharepoint will be using Active Directory for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/f77d03bd-5cab-48bd-b16e-aaec809c24c7

Another links:
http://www.usingnat.net/sharepoint/2011/2/23/how-to-programmatically-authenticate-to-uag-protected-sharep.html
http://blackninjasoftware.com/2009/04/09/how-to-programmatically-impersonate-users-in-sharepoint/
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/00a41275-bdb3-4987-b7f7-1b0fc265cb3e